# Can someone help me solve this in c#

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I use xsd.exe /classes cwmp-1-1.xsd to generate c# code.

The following code is generated by the tool.

```
public partial class Array 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string arrayType;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string offset;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool offsetSpecified;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "ID")]
    public string id;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "anyURI")]
    public string href;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr;
}

public partial class EventList : Array
{
}

public partial class EventStruct
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string EventCode;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string CommandKey;
}

public partial class Inform
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public DeviceIdStruct DeviceId;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public EventList Event;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public uint MaxEnvelopes;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public System.DateTime CurrentTime;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public uint RetryCount;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ParameterValueList ParameterList;
}
```

and my code

```
Inform inform = new Inform();
inform.Event = new EventList();

EventStruct es = new EventStruct();
es.EventCode = "0 BOOTSTRAP";
es.CommandKey = "";
```

My problem is how to add `es` to `inform.Event`

and how to Serializer/Deserialize class Inform.

Answer (score 0):

1st part of your question.

```
inform.Event = es;
```

2nd part of your question, here is some of my code, adapted for your situation.

To Deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Inform));
Inform ifnorm = null;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader((FileName))
{
    inform = (Inform)serializer.Deserialize(sr)
}
```

I think you can figure out the Serialization from this link to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx).

Comment: `inform.Event` is of type `EventList`, not `EventStruct`. I don't see any field of type `EventStruct`; however, what we see are partial classes. Does another part of `EventStruct` not shown here derive from `EventList`?

Comment: You might need to do the following to add the event:  inform.Event.Add(es);

Comment: inform.Event = es;  it's not right
And inform.Event not have Add method

Comment: I cann't and any type derive from EventList

Comment: Ok, try inform.Event[0] = es;